# Return from a get based on the value being null or "00"

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me if this is valid code:

```
get
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(TopicID) ? null : 
           TopicID == "00" ? "All Topics" :     
           int.Parse(TopicID).ToString();
}
```

I want the get to return a null, return the words "All Topics" if it is "00" or return the number without leading zeros.

The code looks messy but I am not sure if there's a more clean way for me to code it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will tell you whether or not it's valid code :)

Others may suggest using `if` statements instead of the conditional operator. I'm happy enough with the conditional operator here, but I'd change the formatting for clarity:

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(TopicID) ? null 
    : TopicID == "00" ? "All Topics" 
    : int.Parse(TopicID).ToString();
```

This is one example of this pattern:

```
[assignment or return] = condition-1 ? value-1
    : condition-2 ? value-2
    : condition-3 ? value-3
      ...
    : fallback-value;
```

I've found this pattern to be quite helpful and readable. The fact that it looks a *little* like F# is entirely coincidental :)

Comment: Jon, this kind of formatting is just perfect and what I was looking for. Now it looks a lot more clean.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid but seems messy indeed. Using standard `if`/`else` should make it cleaner:

```
get
{
    int id;
    if (!int.TryParse(TopicID, out id))
    {
        return null;
    }
    return id == 0 ? "All Topics" : id.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ok - I would try to make the intent more clear like

```
return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TopicID) ? null 
               : (TopicID == "00" ? "All Topics" 
                          : int.Parse(TopicID).ToString()));
```